# 400 Bad Request: The browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, postman

I had this code from a YouTube video of codeside academy. worked good for him but I am experiencing issues. Console errors:

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/talk' from origin 'null' has been blocked 
    by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

    POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/talk net::ERR_FAILED
```

SERVER errors-

```
    werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request 
    that this server could not understand.
    KeyError: 'user_input'
```

I have these files

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import trainer
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/api/talk',methods=['POST'])
def index():
    user_input = request.form['user_input']
    return jsonify({'msg':str(trainer.brain(user_input))})

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

and , api.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src=""></script>
    <script src=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Let's Talk</h1>

    <div id="userinput" class="alert alert-success" role="alert"></div>
    <div id="botresponse" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
    <input type = "text" name = "user_input" class="input-small"><br><br>
    <button onclick="sendToServer()" class="btn btn-success" id="button">Send</button>
    <span></span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function sendToServer(){
        console.log("clicked")
        $.ajax({
            data :{
                user_input: $("#user_input").val()
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/talk" ,
            contentType: "application/json" ,
            headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " ,
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            let user = $("#user_input").val()
            document.getElementById("userinput").innerText=user,
            document.getElementById("botresponse").innerText=data.msg
        })
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The server.py was working fine with Postman until I changed .json to .form there in order to integrate the API.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Might be missing a star at the end of this line `headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " ,`
Change that to be `headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" ,` in your javascript code in your html file.

Comment: @CAM_344 This doesn't work. Please suggest something else.

Comment: your main problem is that `$("#user_input").val()` means you get value from element which has `id="user_input"` but your `<input>` has only `name="user_input"`

Answer (score 1):

Error `KeyError: 'user_input'` means you try to get `form["user_input"]` but there is no `"user_input"` in `form` - probably browser doesn't send it - for example if you get `GET` request then it may not have it.

You can check `print(request.form)` to see what you get in `form`

And you can use `form.get('user_input')` to get `None` when there is no `'user_input'` in form

```
user_input = request.form.get('user_input')
```

Or you should check key before you get it and send something different when there is no key

```
if 'user_input' in request.form
     user_input = request.form.get('user_input')
     return jsonify({'msg':str(trainer.brain(user_input))})
else:
     return "WRONG DATA"
```

Or maybe simply you should check if you get `POST` requests

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     user_input = request.form.get('user_input')
     return jsonify({'msg':str(trainer.brain(user_input))})
else:
     return "HELLO WORLD"
```

---

**BTW:**

Today was similar problem with `KeyError` in question [HTML range slider to Flask with AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593749/html-range-slider-to-flask-with-ajax-call)

---

**EDIT:**

You have few mistakes in `JavaScript` code

Code `$("#user_input").val()` means you want to get value from element which has `id="user_input"` but your `<input>` has only `name="user_input"`. You have to add `id="user_input"`.

To send headers you need dictionary

```
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```

To send as JSON you need to convert data to JSON

```
data: JSON.stringify({ user_input: $("#user_input").val() }),
```

and then you have to use `request.json` instead of `request.form

```
user_input = request.json['user_input']
```

---

Minimal working example.

I used `render_template_string` to put all code in one file - so everyone can simply run it.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template_string
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/api/talk', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('form:', request.form)
        print('data:', request.data)
        print('json:', request.json)
        user_input = request.json['user_input']
        return jsonify({'msg': 'My Answer'})
    else:
        return render_template_string('''<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src=""></script>
    <script src=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Let's Talk</h1>

    <div id="userinput" class="alert alert-success" role="alert"></div>
    <div id="botresponse" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
    <input type="text" id="user_input" class="input-small"><br><br>
    <button onclick="sendToServer()" class="btn btn-success" id="button">Send</button>
    <span></span>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendToServer(){
        console.log("clicked");
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({ user_input: $("#user_input").val() }),
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/talk",
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            let user = $("#user_input").val();
            document.getElementById("userinput").innerText=user;
            document.getElementById("botresponse").innerText=data.msg;
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```